# My nested Class collection XMLRoot name is not being used when serializing to xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a Model populated and I wish to serlise to an xml document.

Due to naming conventions I have to over ride the class names for my XML document,

This is my Model(s):

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("preferences")]
public class PreferencesModel
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string MessageToUser { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sectiondivider")]
    public List<SectionDivider> SectionDivider { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sectiondivider")]  
public class SectionDivider
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("preference")]
    public List<PreferenceModel> PreferenceModel { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("preference")]
public class PreferenceModel
{

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }       

    [XmlElement("options")]
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
```

this is how I serialize:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(ObjectToXmlString(obj, includeNameSpace, includeStartDocument, rootAttribute));
return xDoc;

public static string ObjectToXmlString(Object obj, bool includeNameSpace, bool includeStartDocument, XmlRootAttribute rootAttribute)
    {
        SpecialXmlWriter stWriter = null;
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = default(XmlSerializer);
        string buffer = null;
        try
        {
            if (rootAttribute == null)
            {
                xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            }
            else
            {
                xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), rootAttribute);
            }
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            stWriter = new SpecialXmlWriter(memStream, new UTF8Encoding(false), includeStartDocument);

            if (!includeNameSpace)
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces xs = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                //To remove namespace and any other inline 
                //information tag                      
                xs.Add("", "");
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stWriter, obj, xs);
            }
            else
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stWriter, obj);
            }
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.ToArray());    
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg = e.Message;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stWriter != null)
                stWriter.Close();
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
XmlDocument preferencesxml = Codec.ObjectToXml(m.SectionDivider,false,
         false, new XmlRootAttribute("preferences"));
```

My m value is:

[image]

and my resulting XML is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlRootAttribute`, as the name suggests, only applies to the root element of the XML being serialised.

You need to use `XmlTypeAttribute` in this context:

```
[XmlType("sectiondivider")]`
public class SectionDivider
{
    //...
}
```

As an aside, the `[Serializable]` attribute is not relevant to `XmlSerializer` - it can be removed unless you need it for some other purpose.

Comment: Ah.. thanks for that. And yes, you are correct 'serialzable' tag is no longer required. I keep forgetting! thank you

Comment: this just made my day, thx!! i was struggling with XmlElement(ElementName = "") but this does not work for a type which is used in an array